# How do I send multiple querystring parameters in ios?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-formatting

**Here is my code**

Passing parameters to my Querystring gives me Bad Access Error!

```
NSString *myJson = @"http://mySite.com/Service.svc/MyList";
myJson = [myJson stringByAppendingFormat:@"?id=%@&uid=%@", firstId, secondId];
```

Can someone help me out!

Comment: Are `firstId` and `secondId` of NSString type?

Comment: firstId is NSString but secondId is not!

Comment: ifrstId is an NSString??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do here is simple string formatting.

Given what you are doing, I guess firstId & secondId are integers, not objects, so your error is because you don't use the right format.

The format `%@` in you `stringByAppendingFormat` is for displaying an object, or more precisely the string returned by its `description` selector.

If you want to format an integer, just use `%d` as in C :)

This will give you :

```
NSString *myJson = @"http://mySite.com/Service.svc/MyList";
myJson = [myJson stringByAppendingFormat:@"?id=%d&uid=%d", firstId, secondId];
```